# Merge two sorted Linked List

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I had a doubt in this problem: [link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/merge-two-sorted-linked-lists) I am following this solution:

```
if((headA==NULL)&&(headB==NULL)
    return NULL;
if((headA!=NULL)&&(headB==NULL))
    return headA;
if((headA == NULL)&&(headB!=NULL))
    return headB;
if(headA->data < headB->data)
    headA->next = MergeLists(headA->next, headB);
else if(headA->data > headB->data)
{
    Node* temp = headB;
    headB = headB->next;
    temp->next = headA;
    headA = temp;
    headA->next = MergeLists(headA->next, headB);
}
return headA;
```

I get that when `headA->data < headB->data` then we simply move the headA pointer to the next node. But when `headA->data > headB->data`, then we create a temp pointer, point it where headA is pointing and move headB to next node. What I don't get is:

1. How are the nodes which are previously sorted get linked to this new temp node that I have created? Can you please point it out on my code
2. Also, where is headA pointer pointing to after the second condition? Is it pointing at the new node?

Comment: If you step through the code with your debugger it will show you exactly what is going on and they value of everything as it happens.

Comment: This doesn't work if the lists have a common data value.  Try merging a list with a copy of the same list.

Comment: You are missing at least one `)` in the code shown.

Comment: This function is recursive, but not tail recursive.  It will fail (with a stack overflow!) given a sufficiently long pair of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code effectively moves the head element from list B to list A.

```
Node* temp = headB;
headB = headB->next;
```

`temp` is pointing at the list B head, and `headB` is pointing at the list B tail.  In effect, the list B head has been popped off the list.

```
temp->next = headA;
```

The list A is now appended to the popped head.

```
headA = temp;
```

And list A is now set to the list with the original head from list B followed by the original list A.

The merge then proceeds exactly as if list A had the smaller head, which it now does because the next element in list B cannot be smaller than it.

This code fails to handle the case that both lists have the same head data value.  In that case, it just returns list A without merging the tails.

Not sure why you can't just do this for the last two cases:

```
if(headA->data < headB->data) {
    headA->next = MergeLists(headA->next, headB);
    return headA;
}
else {
    headB->next = MergeLists(headA, headB->next);
    return headB;
}
```

And keep it simple and symmetric.

You can also simplify the first three cases to the following two:

```
if(headA == NULL)
    return headB;
if(headB == NULL)
    return headA;
```

This can also be done without recursion:

```
Node *merge_lists(Node *headA, Node *headB)
{
    Node *head;
    Node **nextPtr = &head;

    while (headA && headB) {
        Node **headMin = (headA->data < headB->data) ? &headA : &headB;
        *nextPtr = *headMin;
        nextPtr = &(*headMin)->next;
        *headMin = *nextPtr;
    }

    *nextPtr = headA ? headA : headB;
    return head;
}
```